# App inventor duplicate button with pressing a button

Tags: app-inventor

How to program a button which actually just should create another button with the same function like another existing one?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErtFX.png)

[image]

I want to add another Button with the same Funktion like the one on the top on the left side.
I know, it would be possible to just add several another buttons and switching visible to true and false, but that would mean that I had to add the elements manually and the number of these buttons would be limited which I would try to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using an extension...
You might want to look into the [Dynamic Component Extension](http://community.appybuilder.com/t/extension-dynamiccomponent-extension/859?u=taifun) by Appybuilder
For a list of available extensions, see https://puravidaapps.com/extensions.php